# Google Apps Script deploy with Google Calendar Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using the script given by google [**Syncing calendar conference changes**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/conferencing/sync-calendar-changes) to get the Google Calendar events and I am going to perform the Sync from Google Calendar to Webex Calendar.
It is working as expected with my account (1 User)

Now I wanted to deploy this add-on to all my users in my Organization.
Since this script is depending on Google Calendar Trigger.
Being an admin, I don't know how to deploy this add-on script to all my users approx 5k.

- I noticed only 100 Google Calendar Triggers can be enabled per Google
  Script. I wanted to know how to deploy this add-on to 5000 users.

  I am the owner of the script but I am unable to delete the Trigger
  from my Google Script of an user ,if the user don't want to use this
  feature. Delete option is disabled. I can only delete the trigger
  which is created by myself.

Please let me know **How to deploy Google Apps Script to 5000 Users with Google Calendar Trigger**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have Google Apps Script Add-on with Calendar Trigger, When I deploy to other users, they can use the service by login to Add-on, but once they leave my organization, I am unable to delete the trigger created in my Google Script since they are the owner of that trigger.

Comment: Again I ask what is the question?

Comment: Question: How to deploy Google Apps Script to 5000 Users with Google Calendar Trigger

Comment: I would advise you to post the question into your question.

Comment: I updated my post with the Question.

Comment: Why don't you let your users create the own trigger.  You can make it easy for them by providing a script that will do it for them.

Comment: I am the owner of the Script and Calendar Trigger is getting created when users login with the script, But when they leave the organization, I am unable to delete the trigger created in my script of them.

Comment: Can't the admin do that?

Comment: No Admin can't do that.

Comment: Really, are they not allowed to manage other's accounts or perhaps they just don't know how?  I would suspect the latter.

Comment: Was the add-on deployed internally within your Google Workspace organization? You can choose to set the Add-On as a domain-installed app instead based on the Organisational Unit but your add-on needs to deployed through Google Workspace Marketplace. Read more here: 

[https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172482?hl=en)